# Is there a way to retrieve saved audiences from the Linkedin Ads API?

Tags: linkedin-api, ads, targeting

When creating campaigns for LinkedIn Ads you can save a target audience template so that the same audience can easily be used for another campaign again. Is it possible to retrieve those saved audiences and save them to a campaign with the Api as well? The documentation only provides information about matched audiences and retrieving targetingFacets and targetingEntities, whereas it would be a lot easier to use those saved audience templates to create campaigns.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge.... no ! But Linkedin ads is evolving quite fast... so let's wait !